# Passing the result of a component to render returns an undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to write a wrapper component around an API call to render "loading" if the api hasnt updated. Im very new to react, but I can t seem to figure out why the state isnt being passed to the **ApiResp** component:

Here is the console.log of the state changes..... why is the final apiResp in console.log undefined?

[image]

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
    let xx = await axios.get(apiUrl)
    console.log(`componentDidMount`, xx)
    this.setState({ loading: false, body: xx });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(`rendering ComponentLoading`, this.state)
    const DisplayComponent = ComponentLoading(ApiResp)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={face} /*className="App-logo"*/ alt="face-img" />
        </header>
        <br></br>
        <div>
          <DisplayComponent isLoading={AppState.loading} body={AppState.body} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

ComponentLoading:

```
import React from 'react';

function ComponentLoading(Component) {
    return function WihLoadingComponent({ isLoading, ...props }) {
        if (!isLoading) return <Component {...props} />;
        return (
            <p style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: '30px' }}>
                Loading
            </p>
        );
    };
}
export default ComponentLoading;
```

apiResp.js

```
import React from 'react';
const ApiResp = (data) => {
    console.log(`apiResp:`, data)
    if (!data || data.statusCode !== 200) {
        return <p>Err: {JSON.stringify(data)}</p>;
    }
    else
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>obj:</h3>
                {JSON.stringify(data)}
            </div>
        );
};
export default ApiResp;
```

Comment: What is `appState` in your component? I don't see it defined in your code. Did you mean `this.state`? I.E `this.state.loading` and `this.state.body`?

Comment: @DrewReese Thats probably what I should use, but when I check `this.state.loading` I get null every time instead of true or false... like the state has never been set or something, which is why I switched to AppState

Comment: Where are you checking the `this.state.loading` state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComponentLoading` is a Higher Order Component. `const DisplayComponent = ComponentLoading(ApiResp)` is decorating the `ApiResp` component:

```
const ApiResp = (data) => {
    console.log(`apiResp:`, data)
    if (!data || data.statusCode !== 200) {
        return <p>Err: {JSON.stringify(data)}</p>;
    }
    else
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>obj:</h3>
                {JSON.stringify(data)}
            </div>
        );
};
```

and returning a component you've called `DisplayComponent`.

As a component `ApiResp` is consuming a props object called `data` and only accesses a `statusCode` prop.

`DisplayComponent` is passed two props:

```
<DisplayComponent isLoading={AppState.loading} body={AppState.body} />
```

`AppState` isn't defined in the parent component but it seems `this.state` has the values you want passed to `DisplayComponent`.

## Solution

Access and pass the correct object to props.

```
<DisplayComponent
  isLoading={this.state.loading}
  body={this.state.body}
/>
```

I suggest also moving the `const DisplayComponent = ComponentLoading(ApiResp)` declaration ***out*** of the render method, and also outside the `App` component.

```
const DisplayComponent = ComponentLoading(ApiResp);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    body: null,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    let xx = await axios.get(apiUrl)
    console.log(`componentDidMount`, xx)
    this.setState({ loading: false, body: xx });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={face} /*className="App-logo"*/ alt="face-img" />
        </header>
        <br></br>
        <div>
          <DisplayComponent
            isLoading={this.state.loading}
            body={this.state.body}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like the state is null, when render is called, so the DisplayComponent line throws errors (it cant find this.state.loading because this.state is null).... but when I try to init the state at the top of render react throws an error

Comment: Your edit did the trick perfectly, Thanks!

Comment: @Rilcon42 Oh, ha, yeah, noticed that you might not've established any initial state and was in the middle of setting up a codesandbox to reproduce your issue and/or confirm my code. You don't want to redeclare your decorated component each render. Glad it's working for you. Cheers.